# Log4J is creating incrementing no of logs in console

Tags: java, log4j

I'm using Log4J for logging in my Java Project with Baic Configurator, which is working in a weird fashion. where it logs statements in console with incrementing number of times.

But If I check my Log File then everything is logged exactly once just like required.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally adding following to my **log4j.properties** solved the problem:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate logging can happen if we have same appender in multiple Logger configurations.

Example

```
log4j.logger.com.demo = WARN, out
log4j.logger.com.demo.moduleone = ERROR, out
```

To avoid it set logger additivity to false.
log4j.additivity.com.demo.moduleone = false